# Select a div by title with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, html, title

I have a webpage with a div which contains several other divs WITHOUT an ID associated to them:

```
<div id="container">
<div   title ="jhon" style=" position:absolute; left: 821px; top: 778.44px; width:8px; height:9px; z-index:3;"> </div> 
<div   title ="carl" style=" position:absolute; left: 561px; top: 579.88px; width:8px; height:9px; z-index:3;"> </div> 
</div>
```

I need to be able to search one of these div by title and then access its style attributes such as left and top.

I am using jQuery but I have no idea on how to select an element by name. I've tried something like:

```
var c =$('div[title~="john"]');
alert(c);               //I get [object Object]
alert(c.style.left)     // throws an error and is undefined
```

but it seems not to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
alert( $("div[title=\"john\"]").css("left") );
alert( $("div[title=\"john\"]").css("top") );
```

or, if the name is a variable:

```
var name = "john";
alert($("div[title=\""+name+"\"]").css("left"));
alert($("div[title=\""+name+"\"]").css("top"));
```

Comment: It works: i've found the problem.. I added the script section on top of the page, before the divs so they didn't exist when the script was called..

Comment: can you explain why did you put title=\" ?? I am trying to be able to search by parameter but if I write var name="john";
alert( $("div[title~="+name+""]').css("top") ); It goes error..

Comment: jquery parse the string $("STRING"), so that if you embed a " character by escaping it like \" then it will be readed correctly by jquery

Comment: so in your case you can write: `var name = "john"; alert( $("div[title=\""+name+"\"]").css("top") );`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("div[title~=john]"); //no quotations inside
```

[Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)