# Scroll to div by its title using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll to a div identified by the content of its `title` attribute. i have few div's with the follwoing structure:

```
<div class="placementWrapper">
   <h3 class="placementName" title="above-content">above-content</h3>
</div>
```

and a button with the following code:

```
<ul id="placemetnsList" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a class="toPlacement" onclick="scrollToPlacement('above-content')">above-content</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="scrollToPlacement('mobile_takeover')">mobile_takeover</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="scrollToPlacement('mobile_toaster')">mobile_toaster</a></li>
</ul>
```

how should `scrollToPlacement(placementName)` implementation look like?

i tried using this code :

```
  function scrollToPlacement(placementName){
    $(".toPlacement[title]").click(function() {
      $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).attr('title')).offset().top - 10}, "slow");
        return false;
      });
    }
```

but didnt work...any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

To select `div` by `title` with jQuery you need this selector:

```
$("div[title=\"the-title\"]")
```

as answered here: [Select a div by title with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152551/select-a-div-by-title-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You have several bugs in your code:

1. You're calling an onclick function that just attaches an event handler. That means that only on your 2nd click you will be scrolled (and also be attaching consecutive handlers). You only want to be attaching one event handler and you can do it on DOM load.
2. According to your structure, you need to search the element's title by the *content* of your clicked element, and not by its title attribute.
3. You're trying to select an element with the ID (#) by the title attribute, which you don't have.
4. `this` inside `$('body')` now refers to `body`, instead of the clicked element.

**Notice you can do all of these attaching dynamically, instead of duplicating your texts.**

This will work for you:

```
$(".toPlacement").on('click', function() {
   var titleText = $(this).text();
   $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(".placementName[title='" + titleText + "']").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
   return false;
});
```

(Remove the onclick from your HTML as well)

Also see a demonstration on this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbpg6800/).